# Python 3.x - Mapping dictionary with multiple tuples as keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, mapping

I have a dictionary containing multiple tuple as keys:

```
dictionary = {('Paris', 'Monaco', 'Marseille'): 'France',
               ('Milan', 'Juventus', 'Roma'): 'Italy',
               ('Manchester', 'Liverpool', 'London'): 'England'}
```

How to mapping list with lot of city names to the dictionary above:

```
lst = ['Paris','Paris','Monaco','Milan','London',...]
```

I have tried this:

```
countries = []
for k,v in dictionary.items():
    for each in lst:
        if each in k:
            countries.append(v)
```

Results: It wasnt assign the city dictionary one-by-one instead listing all keys multiple times

Desired output:

```
lst        countries
Paris       France
Paris       France
Monaco      France
Milan       Italy
London      England
...         ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have that format in your dictionary? Why not make the cities **separate** keys, and duplicate values?

Comment: assume i have lot of keys & values in my dictionary and difficult to make separate keys with duplicate values

Comment: It is *not* difficult to make a new dictionary with separate keys. If you have a lot of keys and values, it is *all the more important* you avoid having to loop over all the keys all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you flatten the dictionary keys. Duplicating values across keys isn't an issue:

```
dictionary = {k: v for tup, v in dictionary.items() for k in tup}
```

Then use the new dictionary to *easily* build your list:

```
countries = [dictionary[city] for city in lst]
```

You can match city and country side by side like so:

```
for city, country in zip(lst, countries):
    print(city, country)
```

Or without building the new `countries` list, you can use the new dictionary directly:

```
for city in lst:
    print(city, dictionary[city])
```

Comment: it works, i think the missing link is i didnt know how to flatten the dictionary keys. Thanks.